# How do you scale an immutable SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, pug

If I have a regular SVG element like this, but it is immutable as in you cannot clone, or change any parameters such as height and width. Is there any way to scale it?

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0" y="0" height="42" width="350">
  <svg xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg2" xml:space="preserve" x="30" y="0" width="80" height="65" viewBox="-200 400 1600 900">
    <metadata>
      ...
    </metadata>
    <g>
      ...
    </g>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: You could put it in a container and apply a transform to the container. Why can't you change any parameters though? If you tell us that then we might avoid making suggestions that won't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an SVG like this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="orange"/>
</svg>
```

You can wrap it in another SVG element where the viewBox matches the size of the original SVG. Now, you can specify a size (width and/or height) or leave it out to make it fill the available space.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="orange"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

You can do the same with the SVG as an external resource (here a data URI for the example) where the width and the height attributes of the image element matches the viewBox of the parent SVG element.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <image width="100" height="100" href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1MCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1MCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEwMCAxMDAiPgogIDxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjUwIiBjeT0iNTAiIHI9IjUwIiBmaWxsPSJvcmFuZ2UiLz4KPC9zdmc+" />
</svg>
```